# ErrorType in swift - how do I get an error code out?

Tags: swift, nserror

I am passed an error - its an `ErrorType` - in a completion.

I can 'po' it in the debugger, but how do I get the number -1009 out in swift code. The only call I can find to make is 'debugDescription'. Is there a Dictionary in there?

Whoever made the ErrorType subclass is basically unknown to me.

```
po error
         ▿ Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet   connection appears to be offline." UserInfo= {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://xxxxxxxxxx.net/token, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://xxxxxxxxxxx.net/token, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, NSUnderlyingError=0x145f7880 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1009 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8}}})
```

Answer (score 5):

Error code comes from Objective C `NSError`. To get the error code first try to cast `ErrorType` to an `NSError`. After you do that you can access the code via `code` property. You can achieve it like this:

```
if let error = error as? NSError {
    print(error.code) // this will print -1009
}
```

For more info, you can refer to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSError/code)

Answer (score 3):

`Xcode 8` and `Swift 3` the conditional cast is always succeeds

```
let errorCode = (error as NSError).code
```

The alternative

```
let errorCode = error._code
```